# What is the source for placing two menorot at the front of the shul, one on either side of the Aron?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, synagogue, menorah--in-temple

Many shuls have menorot at the front of the shul on either side of the aron. I understand that basically this is a zecher l'mikdash. However, is there a source for the minhag to place specifically two menorot? The first Beit Hamikdash only had one menorah, and the second Beit Hamikdash had 11 I think. An additional difference from the Beit Hamikdash is that many shuls have menorot that do not have 7 branches (either more or less) and have a decorative center piece rather than a shamash. Also, some shuls have these menorot attahed to the railing around the bimah. So are these just stylistic choices of the architect or is that a source somewhere?

[Belz Shul in Jerusalem - (2, 4-branched)](http://shaareibina.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/564041_3946422573339_1590506600_n.jpg)

[Carlebach Shul NYC (2, 6-branched)](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_OBFRXzG0ZW0/S_NFAidedAI/AAAAAAAAA7o/a1PjudKyJCA/s1600/Reb+Shlomo's+NY+shul+1995+(c)+Joy+Krauthammer.jpg)

**Update:** A friend of mine suggested that the two menorot might be sourced in the two olive trees in [Zechariah 4:3](http://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.4). I wonder if there are any sources in sifrei Chazal or books of minhagim that make this connection. I would love if someone has a source about this.

Comment: First Bet Mamikdash had 11 - see Melachim-I 7:49 {מט}  וְאֶת הַמְּנֹרוֹת חָמֵשׁ מִיָּמִין וְחָמֵשׁ מִשְּׂמֹאול לִפְנֵי הַדְּבִיר זָהָב סָגוּר וְהַפֶּרַח וְהַנֵּרֹת וְהַמֶּלְקַחַיִם זָהָב:

Comment: Correct. I was mistaken. There was one menorah in the mishkan.